# Connecting Node.js docker container to php container for use with Laravel 5 elixer

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, nginx, laravel-5

I am running several different docker containers that contain PHP, Nginx and a few other tools. I would like to use the new Elixer feature of Laravel 5 but I know nothing about node.js or how to connect to a Node.js container.

All of the tutorials I have read use the installation of Node.js on the same machine, not in separate docker containers or servers that must talk to each other remotely.

I was hoping someone could point me into the right direction because I have no idea even where to start. I know that you can run node as a server and set variables like host and port etc, but I'm not sure if thats what is needed here.

It seems like it since PHP, Nginx, etc will need to speak to node remotely while in their separate containers, but as I said the examples on The Laravel site and other tutorials I have found only show how to run commands etc with node on the same machine. I am lost..